# Change quarter format

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe, df, where I would like to change the column values of a 4 digit quarter date to a two digit

Data

```
id    date

aa    Q1.2022
bb    Q2.2025
aa    Q3.2022
```

Desired

```
id    date

aa    Q1.22
bb    Q2.25
aa    Q3.22
```

Doing

```
df['date'] = pd.PeriodIndex(df['date'], freq='Q').strftime('Q%q.%y')
```

Note:
Pandas version = 1.1.3

Comment: Can't reproduce. `pd.PeriodIndex(['2022-01-01'], freq='Q').strftime('Q%q.%y')` yields `Index(['Q1.22'], dtype='object')`

Comment: Same as @ifly6. I am unable to reproduce the issue. What version of pandas are you using?

Comment: I am using python 3.6 (jupyter notebook) not sure of the pandas version

Comment: `pd.__version__`

Comment: I am using version '1.1.3'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try via `str.split()` and `str.join()`:

```
df['date']=df['date'].str.split('.').str[::-1].str.join('-')
df['date']=pd.PeriodIndex(df['date'],freq='Q').strftime('Q%q.%y')
```

output of `df`:

```
    id  date
0   aa  Q1.22
1   bb  Q2.25
2   aa  Q3.22
```